# programming 3.3V PIC32 board with pic32prog and PICkit 2

Tags: programmer, pickit

I already managed to overwrite the bootloader of my clients's PIC32MX7 board while experimenting with mikroe-uhb. so before I can continue the assignment I need to reprogram it, and all I have on hand is a PICkit 2. I have a PICkit 2 to ICD3 cable on order, but my worry is that the different voltage levels (5VDC on the Pk2, 3.3 on the MMB) could fry the board. googling around, I've seen suggestions for using diodes or resistors, or adding capacitors here and there, but I'm wondering if it really needs to be that complicated. I saw at least one post that indicated if the PICkit2 sees a voltage on the V<sub>DD</sub> line, it won't put out its own. can anyone here tell me authoritatively what the deal is?

[added later]
just for reference, here is the adapter cable I bought: http://www.ebay.com/itm/251569322951

it turns out that its pin numbering is in reverse to the PICkit 2, i.e., hook the blue wire to pin 1 of the Pk2, rather than the white wire. I powered up the mikroe board, then connected the PICkit2 to the ICD3 port and ran pic32prog:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~/rentacoder/jm_____$ pic32prog/pic32prog pic32mx795f512l_bootloader_firmware_v130.hex 
Programmer for Microchip PIC32 microcontrollers, Version 1.96
    Copyright: (C) 2011-2014 Serge Vakulenko
      Adapter: PICkit2 Version 2.32.0
    Processor: MX795F512L
 Flash memory: 512 kbytes
  Boot memory: 12 kbytes
         Data: 12428 bytes
        Erase: done
Program flash: ########################### done
 Program boot: #### done      
 Verify flash: ########################## done
  Verify boot: #### done       
Rate: 1517 bytes per second
```

Comment: I do know that MPLAB is pretty good about warning you of these sorts of dangers.  Try it with the chip disconnected, and see how far you get.

Comment: the chip disconnected? I don't get it. the chip is soldered onto the board that has the ICD3 connector.

Comment: I have a cheap PK2 clone that only does 5V (hard wired output).  I added an LM1117-33 to it to regulate down to 3.3V for use with the pic32 and pic32prog.  You could always knock up a small adaptor to enforce 3.3V if it proves problematic.  I'm not sure pic32prog even cares if there is power or not - You could try programming it while leaving the Vdd line completely disconnected.

Comment: I was saying to connect the programmer, but don't connect it to your board.  MPLAB will connect to the programmer; once it's done that it will try to identify the chip. But before it tries to read the chip, it checks to see if your programmer might damage it.  But I see you aren't using MPLAB.  pic32prog is a different program so this doesn't apply.  Maybe it will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PicKit2 can program 3.3V devices just fine. Look at the [PK2 user guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51553E.pdf), section 3.4.2:

> 3.4.2  The application circuit is powered externally
>
> The PICkit 2 may
> be used with application circuits powered externally between +5.0V and
> +2.5V.

You should look at the whole chapter 3, and compare its requirements / recommendations with the schematic of the board you need to program. But if it has an ICD3 header you probably should be fine.

You can measure, before connecting the PK2 to your board, that it indeed does output the proper voltage on Vdd when controlled by pic32prog (about 3.3V).

(Updated after reading Majenko's answer who did indeed look at the source code)

Answer (score 1):

From the source code of pic32prog:

```
#define VDD_VOLTAGE             3.3     /* Power supply */
#define VDD_LIMIT               2.81
   ...    
/* PICkit 2 */
unsigned vdd = (unsigned) (VDD_VOLTAGE * 32 + 10.5) << 6;
unsigned vdd_limit = (unsigned) ((VDD_LIMIT / 5) * 255);
pickit_send (a, 4, CMD_SET_VDD, vdd, vdd >> 8, vdd_limit);
```

So I guess from that the PICkit 2 is told to power the board at 3.3V.  I'm not sure what the \$V_{DD}\$ limit is for...?

As the PICkit 2 is providing power it should be unable to "sense" power, so it shouldn't care if the power is connected or not.  If you're very paranoid you can power the board externally and connect the PICkit 2 without linking the \$V_{DD}\$ line.  It should still work fine.

Comment: The Vdd limit is used to ensure that the output voltage on Vdd has the right voltage. If its to low (e.g. target drawing too much current) the PicKit will report an error.

Comment: So it's a lower limit, that's good.